# Jenkins Conditional Stage Changeset Always Skipped

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to add conditions to a Jenkins stage so it will only trigger when there's been a change to a `.yaml` file in the changeset

The code I've ended up trying is:

```
when {
    changeset '*.yaml'
}
```

According to the following site, this should cause the stage to be run when there is a change to a `*.yaml` file in the changeset, however this stage is always being skipped

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong, or what else I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins must have first collected the changelog e.g. checkout scm.
When you just run `checkout scm` in a jenkins pipeline it will tell you:
ERROR: ‘checkout scm’ is only available when using “Multibranch Pipeline” or “Pipeline script from SCM”.

So add your pipeline in a Jenkinsfile to your repository.
My repository contains a file `test.yaml` and a file `Jenkinsfile` with this pipeline:

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('checkout'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git'
            }
        }

        stage('test'){
            when {
                changeset "*.yaml"
            }
            steps{
                echo "The file did change in the last commit (SCM checking)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it will work. When there was a change in Git in your file you will see:

```
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
The file did change in the last commit (SCM checking)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

And else if there was no change:

```
[Pipeline] { (test)
Stage "test" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: Looks like this is the way to go!  


One caveat is that my repository is private, which is causing me issues in the `branch` stage  


The Jenkins task is being kicked off when the `'master'` branch is being updated, however, is there any chance that this mechanism causes the changeset to be passed into the Jenkinsfile somehow?

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue with the private repo/branches. (you can define credentials to the git plugin to clone the repo) Can you explain that a bit more? maybe multibranch pipelines offer an option.

Comment: Hi @lvthillo,
Can you help me, I have a step `checkout` and multibranch pipeline. When I add a folder to the changeset like this it doesn't work ( ) :

`changeset "*/folder1/**"`

Comment: what if you try changeset pattern instead of changest?

Comment: How to specify the folder?

Comment: I had a similar problem. As it was said by lvthillo above, checkout should be first performed. In my case, we used a shared library, which didn't do it actually due to some reasons. So, after the shared library update it started work as expected.